# Connect to encrypted Access database using UCanAccess

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

How can you create a connection to an encrypted Access database using UCanAccess?

```
import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver;

Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://" + sample+ "//db//sample.accdb");
```

Comment: Can you maybe post a more complete example of your code, as well as any errors you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow all steps mentioned (about the parameter JackcessOpener) in the [UCanaccess web site](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html), tab "getting started".

Comment: Hi, Can you provide me a sample code snippet? I'm new to java.